# What bare minimum Android API Level is supported by Sencha Touch 2.0?

Tags: android, sencha-touch, cordova, google-play

Does anyone know the definitive *bare minimum* Android API level supported by Sencha Touch 2?

I found this thread on the Sencha Forums, but the answers that appear there are not definitive:

http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?188298-Sencha-Touch-2.x-application-is-not-working-on-Android-2.1-Emulator%28API-Level-7%29

I have a PhoneGap 1.4.1 (Cordova) Android project and am trying to target only devices supported by ST2.0 in Google Play's market.

Thanks!

Comment: +1 for the background research!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is NOT supported on Honeycomb. Seems OK for me on 2.2, 2.3 and 4

Comment: As I understand it, Honeycomb (Android 3.0, API Level 10) may indeed not be supported by Sencha Touch 2.0.

Comment: Do you have any evidence of Android 2.2 and 2.3 supporting ST2? I have so far been unable to verify this in my testing. It may have worked with ST 1.0, but not 2.0.

Comment: I'm accepting this answer with reservations, I'd still enjoy more evidence if it exists. The Minimum API level should probably be above API Level 10 (Android 3.0 'Honeycomb') to restrict away devices with Honeycomb. I will likely continue to use API level 13 for Android 3.2 given the useage statistics I've seen on our own apps.

Comment: I can only talk about my app, which is fine on 2.2 and 2.3. The "unsupported on Honeycomb" comment is from Sencha on the ST2 support forum. Given Honeycomb is only for tablets, you might be able to consider a phone spin, available on 2.2 up, and a tablet spin for 4.0 and above.

Answer (score 0):

*I might be wrong* but I guess **Android 4+** fully supports Sencha Touch 2.x.

So, the **minimum API** you should specify in your project would be **API level 14**.

Comment: My understanding is there still may be support for at least Android 3.2 (API level 13) and possibly even lower? I'm looking for the lowest API level possible that will still run an ST 2 application. Obviously, I could set API 14 and miss the vast majority of existing devices in the wild. I have done testing on API 13 and all appears well.

Comment: Additionally, I've found that Android 4.0.4 fails to fully support CSS 3 Image masks, required by the ST2 Tabbar views. I've worked around that issue.

Comment: If you are looking for the *bare minimum* API level required to run a ST2 application, I believe you could go for 2.3.3. As per my knowledge, Android 2.3.3 supports majority of the required features of ST2.

Comment: Yes. I'm looking for the bare minimum and I've now edited my question to reflect that requirement. What is interesting is the statement by pinoyid which seems to indicate that even if 2.3.3 works, 3.0 will not. If that is the case, I'll need to target above 3.0 (beyond API Level 10).

Comment: For anyone curious, here is the bug for ST2.0 on the image masks: http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?189661-Bottom-Tabs-no-images-(Android-4.0.3-Browser)

Comment: Yeah, I read that answer too. Did some research and yeah, it seems that he is right. It is supported in 2.3.3 but not in 3.0